# Linq query using Contains to filter id

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have using linq like :

```
Dim requestlist = GetDataContext(Of FirmwareRequestActiveTaskViewModel). _
                  NewRequest.RequestActiveTasks.Where( _
                  Function(x) x.RequestTask.Status = "OPEN").ToList()

Dim requlistChannel = requestlist.Where( _
                      Function(x) x.RequestTask.Task.DepartmentList.Where( _
                      Function(b) b.DepartmentId = 52).Any())
```

In the above query i have deparments sub list I need to check the Depart ID 52 in that list.

I am using contains as follows :

```
Dim deptlst As New List(Of BCOMSDepartment)
Dim dept As New BCOMSDepartment
dept.DepartmentId = 52
deptlst.Add(dept)
Dim requlistIBI = requestlist.Where(Function(x) _  
                  x.RequestTask.Task.DepartmentList.Contains(deptlst))
```

the above query also not working..

Comment: "Not working" doesn't give us anything to help you with. Does it compile? If so, does it throw an exception? If not, are you getting the wrong results? An empty result? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: when I use contains I'am not able to compile.